# ModelSim - Unable To Simulate Button Presses

Tags: vhdl, fpga, modelsim

I want to use four push buttons as inputs and three seven-segment LED displays as outputs. Two push buttons should step up and down through the sixteen RAM locations; the other two should increment and decrement the contents of the currently-displayed memory location. I have the following two entities:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity DE2_TOP is

  port (
    KEY : in std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);         -- Push button
    CLOCK_50: in std_logic;
    );

end DE2_TOP;

architecture datapath of DE2_TOP is

begin  
  U1: entity work.lab1 port map (
    key => key,
    clock => clock_50,        
  );

end datapath;

library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity raminfr is                     -STANDARD RAM INFERENCE
    port (
        clock: in std_logic;
        we : in std_logic;
        a : in unsigned(3 downto 0);
        di : in unsigned(7 downto 0);
        do : out unsigned(7 downto 0)
    );
end raminfr;

architecture rtl of raminfr is

type ram_type is array (0 to 15) of unsigned(7 downto 0);
signal RAM : ram_type;
signal read_a : unsigned(3 downto 0);
begin
process (clock)
begin
    if rising_edge(clock) then
        if we = '1' then
            RAM(to_integer(a)) <= di;
        end if;
        read_a <= a;
    end if;
end process;
do <= RAM(to_integer(read_a));
end rtl;
```

and

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity lab1 is
    port(
        clock : in std_logic;
        key : in std_logic_vector(3 downto 0); 
        );
end lab1;

architecture up_and_down of lab1 is
    signal value_in_ram : unsigned(7 downto 0);
    signal we : std_logic;
    signal value_counter    : unsigned(7 downto 0) ;
    signal register_counter : unsigned(3 downto 0);
        begin
    U1: entity work.raminfr port map (
        a   => register_counter,
        di  => value_counter,
        do  => value_in_ram,
        clock => clock,
        we  => we
    );

    process(clock)
        begin
            if rising_edge(clock) then
                if (key(3)='0' and key(2)='0' and key(1)='1' and key(0)='0') then
                    value_counter <= value_counter + "1";   
                elsif (key(3)='0' and key(2)='0' and key(1)='0' and key(0)='1') then  
                    value_counter <= value_counter - "1";   
                elsif (key(3)='1' and key(2)='0' and key(1)='0' and key(0)='0') then
                    register_counter<= register_counter + "1";
                    value_counter <= value_in_ram;
                elsif (key(3)='0' and key(2)='1' and key(1)='0' and key(0)='0') then
                    register_counter<= register_counter - "1";
                    value_counter <= value_in_ram;
                end if;
            end if;
    end process;
end architecture up_and_down;
```

I also have the following test bench, where I try to simulate buttons being pressed via KEY:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;


entity DE2_TOP_TEST is
end;

architecture BENCH of DE2_TOP_TEST is

    signal KEY :  std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
    signal CLOCK_50 :  std_logic := '0';
    signal hex4, hex5, hex6 :  std_logic_vector(6 downto 0);           
begin
    clock_50 <= not clock_50 after 50 ns;
    process
        begin
            KEY<="0010";
                    wait for 1 us;
        KEY<="0000";
    end process;

uut:work.DE2_TOP port map (                                                         
    KEY=>key,
    CLOCK_50=>clock_50, 
    hex4=>hex4,
hex5=>hex5,
hex6=>hex6                                 
);
end BENCH;
```

My test bench set up looks like this:

[image]

To simulate, I compile all three of the above files, and then simulate DE2_TOP_TEST, but am met with the result that my "KEY" is still undefined, as below (although CLOCK_50 does get the default value that I set):

[image]

Anyone know what's causing this?

Comment: Two small things: There should be a 'wait' after the assignment to 'key' in the process.  Second: where is this clock coming from (both 'clk' and 'clock'.  (sorry, don't have the time to do more)

Comment: So, you have 'UUUU' at key.  But at which time is that?  Anyhow, all you signals are 'U'.  Could it be you did not started the simulation yet?  Try 'run -all' in the TCL windows of Modelsim.  And break it after some time.

Comment: "clk" is from my raminfr entity, "clock" is from lab 1. I am not sure if they should be port mapped together or not - at the moment, they are not, but I have tried doing it, and it didn't change the result. I also tried the run -all with no change.

Comment: another note: your VHDLfiles are called '*.vho'.  Well, nothing wrong with it, although '*.vhdl' or '*.vhd' would be more natural.  But could it not be you're simulating the netlist after synthesis or implementation? At those stages, you can write out the netlist in a VHDL netlist to simulate if the design is still working.

Comment: I have the .vhd files in another folder. I only compiled the .vho because that was the first folder opened to me by ModelSim. I just tried compiling the .vhd files instead - I was able to successfully compile lab1.vhd and DE2_TOP.vhd, but not DE2_TOP_TEST.vhd, which gives me an error. Could the problem be that I actually need to be simulating the DE2_TOP_TEST file, instead of lab1?

Comment: Could you share the error message?  You have to compile all vhdl files (design and testbench) and you have to simulate your testbench.  The simulator will build the design by connecting all sub modules (=elaborating).

Comment: The error message is as follows: "(vcom-1141) Identifier "DE2_TOP" does not identify a component declaration". It points to the line "uut:work.DE2_TOP port map (" in my test bench.

Comment: "uut: ENTITY work.DE2_TOP"....

Comment: Thanks. I was now able to compile lab1.vhd, DE2_TOP.vhd, and DE2_TOP_TEST.vhd. I then simulated DE2_TOP_TEST and although KEY is still set to UUUU, CLOCK_50 is now set to 0, which is at least a change from before. This is probably because I've set 0 as the default value for CLOCK_50 in my test bench. Perhaps I should do the same for KEY?

Comment: Well, I was able to get KEY set by initializing it in the signals of my test bench (like I did with CLOCK_50). Still haven't had luck in setting it through the actual logic. I am now trying to move my hex values into my test bench so I could actually check if they are correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(1) You have unconnected ports on the entity you are typing to test. The test results are as expected for those inputs - specifically, clk, being undriven.

(2) Having connected clk, you will need to drive it.

```
signal clk : std_logic := '0';
```

and

```
clk <= not clk after 50 ns;
```

should give a 10MHz clock, check this in the simulator

(3) Drive "KEY" with a specific sequence of values

```
subtype keys is std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
constant count_up : keys := "0001";
constant count_dn : keys := "0010";
constant idle     : keys := "0000"; 
-- etc

    process
    begin
        KEY <= count_up;
        wait for 1 us;
        KEY <= idle;
        wait for ...
-- etc
    end process;
```

(4) Bring the OUTPUTS back out into the testbench so that you can check their values. You need to bring them out as ports in the top level (design) entity anyway, if you are going to connect them to a display!

Then (later, once things have started going to plan) you can test them in the testbench process...

```
    wait for 100 ns;
    -- after the last press, we should have "07" on the display
    assert digit(1) = "0111111" report "Left digit has wrong value" severity ERROR;
    assert digit(0) = "0000111" report "Left digit has wrong value" severity ERROR;
```

A self-checking testbench like this saves debugging by staring at waveforms. You only need the waveforms when the tests are failing...

Comment: Could you be a little more specific regarding point number 1? Where exactly is the disconnect?

Comment: I've modified my code to do what you think should be done, but the result is the same.

Comment: You are feeding "clock" into lab1 and using it in the process, but not the memory. That uses "clk" instead which as far as I can see is still undriven. But now you have the tools to make progress yourself - I believe you can see "clock" toggling and "clk" undriven.

Comment: Hey man, I have connected the lab1 and RAM clocks as you wanted (see above edits). Also, I don't know if you read the above comments with the other poster, but I was able to set KEY and CLOCK_50 in my test bench by setting them by default when I initialize them as signals - however, I'm still not able to set KEY using the logic. Also, I don't think setting it this way works - if you look at my edits above, I port the hex values back into my test bench to check them, but they are all undefined in the output.

Comment: There should be a console window in the simulator. Can you post the last few lines of its output?

Comment: +1: "You only need the waveforms when the tests are failing..."